# Object's method getting called on object, when is store in a variable but not when the objects are stored in an array

Tags: javascript

I have defined a class Timeline in Javascript using the constructor method,

```
function Timeline(formal parameters)
{
   //property definitions
}
```

The methods are defined on the prototype object,

```
Timeline.prototype.zoomMax = function(){ // Method Definition };
```

I am using array to store the objects of Timeline,

```
var timeline = [];
timeline[0] = new Timeline(parameter's values);
timeline[1] = new Timeline(parameter's values);
```

But when I am calling the method of Timeline as,

```
timeline[0].zoomMax();
```

I am getting the error,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'zoomMax' of undefined

Note: I have checked printing timeline[0], object is getting stored in it.

When I am storing the object in a simple variable instead of an array, it works fine,

```
var timeline = new Timeline(parameter's values);

timeline.zoomMax(); //Gives me the output
```

I am not getting, how do I call the method zoomMax() on the objects stored in array.

Please guide.

My Timeline Code,

```
function Timeline(video_duration_in_sec,frames_per_sec = 25,zoom_value=1){

            ComponentContainer.call(this,'time-cover');
            this.video_duration_in_sec = video_duration_in_sec;
            this.frame_count = video_duration_in_sec * frames_per_sec;
            this.zoom_value = zoom_value;
            this.ruler_width = this.video_duration_in_sec * (100/this.zoom_value);
            this.min = 1;
            this.max = 25;                     


        }
```

Comment: The error message clearly says that `timeline[0]` is not defined.

Comment: Code works fine as is.

Comment: can you share how your Timeline constructor works?

Comment: your code is working fine try function Timeline()
{
   console.log("hi");
}
Timeline.prototype.zoomMax = function(){ };
var timeline = [];
timeline[0] = new Timeline();
timeline[1] = new Timeline();
timeline[0].zoomMax();

Comment: @George.S I have updated the question with code

Comment: @abhinavxeon Yes your's work fine, also I have following lines of code,                         Timeline.prototype = Object.create(ComponentContainer.prototype);

        Object.defineProperty(Timeline.prototype,'constructor',{
            value: Timeline,
            enumerable: false, 
            writable: true
        });        // are these creating the error

Comment: @abhinavxeon, It was the lines in the comment, that were responsible. I had just used it as it was provided in the tutorial, but removing it fixes it. Can anyone tell, what these lines were doing. As removing them should not give any impact on other end of the code

Answer (score 1):

Use `class` keyword to define object class

```js
class Timeline 
{
    constructor(parameters) {
        //property definitions, initialization...
    }

    zoomMax() {
        console.log('zoom');
    }
}


var timeline = [];
timeline[0] = new Timeline('parameters values');
timeline[1] = new Timeline('parameters values');

timeline[0].zoomMax();
```

Comment: Kielczewski Initially I had done coding using class keyword, as it is not supported in Internet Explorer, I was told to change it

Comment: Use some es6 polyfill for IE e.g babel

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me

```
    function Timeline(params){ ... }

    Timeline.prototype.zoomMax = function() { ... } 

    var timeline = []
    timeline[0] = new Timeline(param1);
    timeline[1] = new Timeline(param2);

    timeline[0].zoomMax(); // Executes zoomMax function
```

Your initial error could have been due to wrong declaration of zoomMax method. More info about this is here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function